# Disable button if paragraph has a specific 'value'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to disable the submit button if the span IDs `par_sku` and `chi_sku` contains the word `undefined`.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJHK87JHK</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span id="par_sku">undefined</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span id="chi_sku">undefined</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJH627HJ</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span id="par_sku">AAA</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span id="chi_sku">BBB</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJKHS2726</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span id="par_sku">CCC</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span id="chi_sku">DDD</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input id="emptyBut" type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The duplicate id is a rule violation, use class instead of id.

Comment: you can use `keyup` to get `text()` of span, but here you having multiple span with same id, so use `class` instead of `id` as per above comment

Comment: Okay but this is system generated. There are hundreds of `form-row`. If every `par_sku` and `chi_sku` is different, it would become impossible to detect using jquery/js and disable the buttons.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I can use class. Could you let me know how to use keyup and text()?

Comment: @ElaineByene yes wailt will show you.

Comment: Is it required that both elements are kind of siblings? (Both in the same `div class=form-row` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains` selector in `jQuery` -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $('.form');
  var isParSkuUndefined = $form.find('span#par_sku:contains(undefined)').length > 0;
  var isChiSkuUndefined = $form.find('span#chi_sku:contains(undefined)').length > 0;
  if (isParSkuUndefined && isChiSkuUndefined) {
    $("#emptyBut").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJHK87JHK</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span id="par_sku">undefined</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span id="chi_sku">undefined</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJH627HJ</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span id="par_sku">AAA</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span id="chi_sku">BBB</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJKHS2726</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span id="par_sku">CCC</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span id="chi_sku">DDD</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input id="emptyBut" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Although, you should classes instead of ids if they are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `text` inside your span and then compare it with somevalue(undefined) if true set some variable to `false` .Depending on this add or remove disabled from submit button.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var flag = true;
$(".form-row").each(function() {
  //get text and compare
  if (($(this).find(".par_sku").text().trim() == "undefined") && ($(this).find(".chi_sku").text().trim() == "undefined")) {
    flag = false //set flag
  }

})
console.log(flag)
if (!flag) {
  $("#emptyBut").attr('disabled', true) //add
} else {
  $("#emptyBut").removeAttr('disabled') //remove 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJHK87JHK</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="par_sku">undefined</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="chi_sku">undefined</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJH627HJ</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="par_sku">AAA</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="chi_sku">BBB</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJKHS2726</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="par_sku">CCC</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="chi_sku">DDD</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input id="emptyBut" type="submit" value="Login"  />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something below**

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
  disableSubmitIfNeeded();
 
 });
 

 function disableSubmitIfNeeded(){
 
  $('#emptyBut').attr('disabled',false);
  $('.par_sku').each(function(i, obj) {
      if($(obj).text() == 'undefined'){
        $('#emptyBut').attr('disabled',true);
      }
  });
  $('.chi_sku').each(function(i, obj) {
      if($(obj).text() == 'undefined'){
        $('#emptyBut').attr('disabled',true);
      }
  });
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJHK87JHK</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="par_sku">undefined</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="chi_sku">undefined1</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJH627HJ</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="par_sku">AAA</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="chi_sku">BBB</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>Keyword</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span>KJKHS2726</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="par_sku">CCC</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="">DDD</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input id="emptyBut" type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```